# Calculating distance of polygons from coastline using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, distance

I have a series of polygons representing parcels of land. I would like to calculate the distance of each polygon from the coastline. I also have a polygon of the entire region of interest, i.e. an island.

What is the ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 procedure to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the assumption that you have an Advanced level license (you do not specify otherwise), I think you should try the [Near (Analysis)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) tool:

> Determines the distance from each feature in the input features to the
> nearest feature in the near features, within the search radius.
>
> ...
>
> - Both input features and near features can be point, multipoint, line, or polygon.

If you decide to use ArcGIS Pro instead then its [Near (Analysis) tool is available at all license levels](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm#L_).